# Database Connection error by giving specific IP address

Tags: users, database, installation

I have created database and user and give all the privileges to the user. When I give the IP as database host, it will show the following errors. Giving database host as localhost it will work fine.

I am using phpmyadmin 3.3.2...

The error message is given below.

> Failed to connect to your MySQL database server. MySQL reports the
>   following message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.85.10'
>   (111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely MySQL remote access would be blocked.

You can edit MySQL conf to enable it.
Loginto your remote db server and edit main configuration file.

vim /etc/my.cnf (in case of Linux)

Comment out `skip-networking` by adding `#` before it, should be located under `[mysqld]` and update `bind-address` for the desired IP you are using as connection host.

```
[mysqld]
...
...
bind-address = 192.168.85.10
#skip-networking
```

Comment: you can leave the comment in front of [bind-address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address), mysql will bind to all IP's